# How to diagnose performance problems with SQL Server Views and JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, gwt, jdbc

I have a view defined in SQL server 2008 that joins 4 tables together.  Executing this view in SQL Server Management Studio takes roughly 3 seconds to run and returns about 45,000 records.  My application is written in Java using hibernate to simply do a "from MyViewObject" query in HQL.  When this is run, the execution time is consistently around 45 seconds.  I have also tried simply using JDBC to run this query and received the same level of performance, so I've assumed it has nothing to do with hibernate.

My question: What can I do to diagnose this problem? There is obviously something different between how Management Studio is running the query vs how my application is running the query but I have not been able to come up with much.

The only thing I've come up with as a potentially viable explanation is an issue with the jtds library that contains the driver for SQL Server in Java.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I went back to trying pure JDBC and tried adding the selectMethod and responseBuffering attributes to my connection string but didn't get any improvements.  I also took my JDBC code from my application and ran it from a test program containing nothing but my JDBC code and it ran in the expected 3 seconds.  So to me this seems environmental for the application.

My application is a Google Web Toolkit(GWT) based app, and the JDBC code is being run in my primary RPC Servlet.  Essentially, the RPC method receives the call and immediately executes the JDBC code.  Nothing in this setup gives me much indication of why the performance is terrible though.  I am going to try the JDBC 3.0 driver and see if that works any better, but it doesn't feel like that will fix the issue to me quite yet.

My goal for the moment is to get my query working live with JDBC and then switch it back over to Hibernate so I can keep the testing simple enough.  Thanks for the help so far!

**UPDATE 2**
I'm finally starting to zero in on the source of the problem, though still no idea what the actual issue is.  I opened up the view in SQL Server and copied the SQL statement (rather large) exactly into my code and executed it using JDBC instead of pulling the data from the view and most of the performance issues are gone.  It seems that some combination of GWT, SQL Server Views and JDBC is not working properly here.  I don't see keeping a very large hand-written query in my code as a long term solution, but it does offer a bit more insight.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961078/sql-server-query-running-slow-from-java

Comment: You should maybe rephrase the title of your question, the problem is not Hibernate related at all.

Comment: Good catch after ruling hibernate out, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

setting this will show you the SQL query generated by hibernate. Analyze the query and make sure you are not missing a relationship.

reply for Update 1 and 2:
Like you mentioned, ran the query on your sql query and it seems like it is fast. So another thing to remember about hibernate is that it creates the object that is returned by your query (of course this depends if you initialize lazy obj. Dont remember what it is called). How many objects does your query return? also you can do a simple bench on where the issue is.

For example, before running the query, sysout the current time and then sysout the current time after. do these for all the places that you suspect is slowing your application down.

Answer (score 1):

To analyze the problem you should look up you manual for tools that display the [query or execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx). Maybe you're missing an index on a join column.