# Native query in Spring Boot / Hibernate much slower than executed externally

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have multiple queries that I execute using `entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery).getResultList()` which take tens of seconds (up to a couple of minutes) to execute. I enabled Hibernate logging and executed the very same SQL queries in IntelliJ connecting to the same database. The queries returned in less than 10ms.

The database is embedded H2, the database driver is the same. The queries do not contain any parameters (which eliminates [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104789/184264)). They only return integers (IDs and counts). If I execute the queries two times in a row the second query returns nearly instantaneous. The query execution time is the same whether I allocate 128M or 2048M to the JVM.

The queries don't look too complicated. The only thing I noticed is that someof them have inner select statements on which I join or which I compare with. I guess they're not the actual problem because they can be executed very quickly when not executed from my program.

The rest of the program works just fine and there are other queries which run as fast expected.

This is an example query:

```
SELECT
  USER_ID,
  count(result) AS count
FROM USERAPIACCESS
WHERE USER_ID IN (123)
      AND RESULT IN ('SUCCESSFUL')
GROUP BY USER_ID, RESULT
ORDER BY USER_ID, RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

how many records are in this table ? 
i think the problem is that you dont have pagination here and the application goes to fetch all records that exist in this table

Comment: Couple of ten thousand. Why would that matter if only ten rows of integers are pulled?

Comment: you sure that only ten rows fetch form database ?