# Spring JPA generated query taking way longer to run than it should

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in my DB mapped to one entity in my project. I'm trying to perform a simple select using `findById()` based on the PK's of this entity. This table has 48 million rows, so it's a very heavy table. Hibernate generates a simple SELECT statement to perform this operation. The problem is that this simple SELECT takes in average 3 seconds to run, but if I get the same query and run it in DBeaver or MSSQL, it takes less than 80ms to run. What could be the reasons for this problem?

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private IdMyEntity id;

    // More columns

    @Data
    @Builder
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class IdMyEntity implements Serializable {
        // 7 columns that represent the PK of the entity
    }
}
```

```sql
select
    -- All the columns from the entity
from
    MyEntity myEntity0_
where
    -- All the columns that represent the PK of the entity
```

Comment: There can be a few reasons for that. Have you checked that there are no other queries executed while calling `findById()`? Have you tried to [enable logging the SQL statements being executed by JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249985/4880379)?

Comment: Probably your `@@OPTIONS` are different in DBeaver and SSMS than what your JDBC-based application is using. Some options are plan-affecting by themselves but because SQL Server caches execution plans using a combination of the statement's hash (including whitespace) and the current `@@OPTIONS` value you can get vastly different results (due to differing statistics and cardinality estimates at the time) just by having different options in effect. Highly recommend reading: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @kasptom Only the SELECT statement is being executed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning good idea, but I executed `SELECT @@OPTIONS` in DBeaver and in my project and got the same result, 5432. And by reading the documentation none of the options seems to have anything to do with performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was because our API was sending the parameters encoded as Unicode to the database while the column type was VARCHAR. As a consequence the index for the table was being ignored and therefore the entire table was being scanned during the fetch.

Adding `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` to our JDBC URL solved the problem.

More details can be found here:

- [Hibernate is 1000 times slower than sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999904/hibernate-is-1000-times-slower-than-sql-query)
- [sql server query running slow from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961078/sql-server-query-running-slow-from-java/32867579#32867579)